# Add same item into two separate QListWidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My project involves two separate QListWidgets with the exact same items. My code successfully adds items to the first list but not the second. Someone must have done this before but search results are for removing duplicate items.

Is it possible to add one item into two QListWidgets without creating new items every time? I could work around this but it seems like an opportunity to learn something.

```
for item in listItems:
    itm = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item);
    self.lstOne.addItem(itm);
    self.lstTwo.addItem(itm);         #fills the first but not the second
```

Here is all the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication,  QListWidget)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.lstOne = QListWidget(self)
        self.lstTwo = QListWidget(self)
        self.lstTwo.move(0,  250)

        listItems = ["one",  "two",  "three",  "four"]     

        for item in listItems:
            itm = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item);
            self.lstOne.addItem(itm);
            self.lstTwo.addItem(itm);       #fills the first but not the second


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two lists sharing the same items is a good use case for using `QListView` objects, that share a model. For small lists you can use a `QStandardItemModel`, which contains `QStandardItems`, like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication,  QListView)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.lstOne = QListView(self)
        self.lstTwo = QListView(self)
        self.lstTwo.move(0,  250)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self)

        listItems = ["one",  "two",  "three",  "four"]     

        for item in listItems:
            itm = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
            model.appendRow(itm)

        self.lstOne.setModel(model)
        self.lstTwo.setModel(model)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you have a large list you should consider to implement your own model class (deriving from `QAbstractListModel`). This has the advantage that you don't need to create item classes for all list elements upfront, and thus gives a much better performance.

You can read more about Qt's model-view programming [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html)

Comment: There, I knew I would learn something. Thanks! That seems like a better way. Just for curiosity, why didn't my item get added to both list widgets?

Comment: Because `QListWidgetItem`s are designed to be used in a single `QListWidget` (you can even get a [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#listWidget) from the item to the list widget that contains the item). Trying to use it in two `QListWidgets` therefore results in undefined behavior. BTW if my post answers your question then please mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity and the depth of the answer. Marked as answered and voted.